# save the list of object to cosmos DB (Document DB or mongo DB) from Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We all know that we can save one document at a time in cosmos DB using Azure functions (using out parameter or using return) like:

```
 object outputDocument = new { id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
                                   customObjList= objList 
                             };
```

where objList is a list of custom object.
Now the above outputDocument will return one json Document and the data in DB will be saved in the below format.

```
{
    "id" : "....",
    "customObjList" :[ 
        {
            "_id" : "81afbe1a-3da0-4143-9dc6-0b3bf5252e0d",
            ...
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "2af7e1ac-15ca-424e-8af1-d3e5a2cca8de",
            ....
        },
        .....
]}
```

**But what I want is something like below list of documents to be saved directly from Azure functions**

```
 /* 1 */
    {
     "_id" : "81afbe1a-3da0-4143-9dc6-0b3bf5252e0d",
     ...
    }
    /* 2 */
    {
      "_id" : "2af7e1ac-15ca-424e-8af1-d3e5a2cca8de",
       ....
    }
```

[To me the requirement is to fetch the data from rss feed and save it to cosmos DB, which I am first reading it and storing the data in a list of object but unable to save those list of object independently in cosmos DB]

Comment: Why not just do a direct write (or writes) to Cosmos DB, from your function?

Answer (score 2):

You can save multiple documents at a time by using `ICollector` or if you have an async function, using the `IAsyncCollector`.

This is how you would output multiple objects:

```
public static void Run(ICollector<object> myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    foreach (object obj in objList)
    {
        var objnew = { 
                        id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
                        someProperty = obj.someProperty
                     };

        myQueueItem.Add(objnew);
    }
}
```

Source: [Azure Documentation -- Writing multiple output values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#writing-multiple-output-values)